# Как поймать deadlock в multiprocessing в Python?

Tags: python, многопоточность, процесс

В университете дали задание с использованием потоков/процессов и одна из задач состоит в том, что при доступе к одному и тому же файлу двумя потоками, должна возникнуть ошибка, мол невозможно получить двумя потоками доступ к одному файлу (эта ошибка решается добавлением Rlock). Посколку в Python "обитает" GIL, то было принято решение воспользоваться модулем multiprocessing, а как это реальзовать... непонятно.

```py
def worker1(word):
    f = open("file.txt", 'w')
    f.write(word)
    f.close()

def worker2(word):
    f = open("file.txt", 'w')
    f.write(word)
    f.close()

multiprocessing.Process(target=worker1('worker1'),).start()
multiprocessing.Process(target=worker2('worker2'),).start()
```

Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Ваш код потоков не запускает. И к чему вы упомянули GIL непонятно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я клонил к тому, что с GIL нельзя получить ошибку с доступом. А как тогда сделать чтоб запускались? В вопросе под потоками я подразумевал процессы, но если это можно реализовать потоками из созданного процесса, то расскажите, пожалуста, как это сделать

Comment: вы, как минимум, даже не запустили процессы. чтобы запустить, нужно запустить метод `start()`

Comment: @MrMorgan, да-да, я забыл их в во написать, спасибо, но всё равно, я что -то не так делаю, если знаете как это правилно сделать, расскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: @JackWolf с GIL можно получить ошибку с доступом, так как на время выполнения системных задач вроде чтения файла этот самый GIL освобождается и даёт поработать другим потокам

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, а как это сделать, если несложно, объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: Вы код назад верните. А то вообще неясно о чём разговор... :)

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, вернул, но это, так сказать, тестовая ситуация. Если вы знаете как реализовать такую "проблему", расскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: https://geekbrains.ru/posts/python_multithreading_pt2

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, спасибо, но я это читал и там не совсем то, что мне нужно. Там идёт акцент на неправильную работу с переменной и всё же, когда убирается блокировка, код отрабатывает. В моей ситуации, должна возникнуть ошибка с доступом или что-то в этом духе. Перед тем как задать вопрос, я читал статьи и там, к сожалению, ничего не освещается по моей проблеме

Comment: Беда в "должна возникнуть ошибка с доступом или что-то в этом духе". Вы, похоже, не совсем понимаете, что должно случиться и почему. Ошибку доступа при записи одного файла несколькими потоками вы не получите. Только мешанину записанных данных. Чтобы получить взаимоблокировку, надо чтобы каждый поток эксклюзивно блокировал что-то. Например упомянутый вами RLock. По ссылке это есть.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, понял, тогда такой вопрос, такое невозможно именно на потоках cpython, а если попытаться реализовать это на ironpython? Или потоки написать на c++ или c#, а потом «прикрутить» к своему коду?

Comment: Дело не в потоках, а в возможности разделяемого доступа к файлам. Если код на C++ не воспользуется платформозависым вызовом для открытия файла в режиме эксклюзивного доступа, то работать будет так же, как код на Python.

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, а возможно ли вообще такое реализовать? Может если приплести сюда виндовс сервисы?

Comment: Ловите ответ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Windows

Вот такая демка должна быть достаточна.
Файл открывается с флагом 0 в `dwShareMode`, что означает

> Prevents other processes from opening a file or device if they request delete, read, or write access.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD

CREATE_ALWAYS = 2
GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000

def worker(word,i):
    print('Started {}'.format(i))
    try:
        handle = ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateFileA("file.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, None, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, None )
        if handle == -1:
            # ctypes.WinError sets up an GetLastError API call for windows as an Python OSError exception.
            # So we use this to raise the error to our caller.
            raise ctypes.WinError()
        print('Process {}: File opened successfully'.format(i))
        time.sleep(2)
        written = DWORD()
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteFile(handle, word, len(word), ctypes.byref(written), None)
        print('Process {}: Write completed'.format(i))
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Process {}: Cannot access file'.format(i))
        print('{}: {}'.format(type(e).__name__,e.args))
    print('Finished {}'.format(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(2):
        multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('worker{}'.format(i),i)).start()
```

Выводит:

```
Started 0
Process 0: File opened successfully
Started 1
Process 1: Cannot access file
PermissionError: (13, 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.', None, 32)
Finished 1
Process 0: Write completed
Finished 0
```

---

### Posix

Сейчас ничего под рукой нет, чтобы протестировать, но должно работать. :)

Здесь приходится явно лочить файл после открытия. А так как это блокирующая операция, то делаем timeout при помощи модуля signal и соответствующей обвязки.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

import signal, errno
from contextlib import contextmanager
import fcntl

@contextmanager
def timeout(seconds):
    def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
        pass

    original_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)

    try:
        signal.alarm(seconds)
        yield
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, original_handler)

def worker(word,i):
    print('Started {}'.format(i))
    with timeout(1):
        try:
            f = open("file.txt", "w")
            print('Process {}: File opened successfully'.format(i))
            fcntl.flock(f.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX)
            print('Process {}: File locked successfully'.format(i))
            time.sleep(3)
            f.write(word)
            print('Process {}: Write completed'.format(i))
            fcntl.flock(f.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
            print('Process {}: File unlocked'.format(i))
            f.close()
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.EINTR:
                raise e
            print('Process {}: Cannot access file'.format(i))
        print('Finished {}'.format(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(2):
        multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=('worker{}'.format(i),i)).start()
```

Comment: ого, спасибо большое
скажите, пожалуйста, а есть ли аналог ctypes.wintypes для unix (просто, у меня MacOS), а винду как-то не очень хочется ставить?

Comment: @JackWolf Что ж Вы сразу не сказали? Как  Sergey Gornostaev указал, демка будет платформно-зависимая. Сейчас посмотрю насчет posix

Comment: что - то забыл) Посмотрите, пожалуйста, если несложно, тем более благодаря вашему ответу я узнал о новой библиотеке

Comment: Ещё раз, спасибо большое!

Comment: всё работает, но в конце возникает ошибка "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file", как её решить?

Comment: @JackWolf, я поправил. `f.close()` переехал пониже...